# Android exit transition excludeTarget not working inside android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-transition

I have an activity which includes a viewpager with 3 fragments. From the first tab, I am calling another activty and trying to exclude toolbar and tab bar from the exit transition.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

                    getActivity().getWindow().setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.LEFT).excludeTarget(R.id.toolbar,true));

                    Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create((View) matCvr, matCvr.getTransitionName());
                    Pair<View, String> pair2 = Pair.create((View)matTxt, matTxt.getTransitionName());

                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),pair1,pair2);
                    ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(), matIntent, options.toBundle());
                }
```

The issue is excludeTarget seems not working and the whole view is sliding to Left.
I have tried addTarget like below for including viewpager alone.But in that case, the default Fade animation is happening.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.LEFT).addTarget(R.id.viewPager));
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Any help appreciated.

### Update

The issue appears when I have the views inside

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout / android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We need to make android:transitionGroup="false" explicitly for the parent views.

[True if the ViewGroup should be acted on together during an Activity transition. The default value is true when there is a non-null background or if getTransitionName() is not null or if a non-null ViewOutlineProvider other than BACKGROUND was given to setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider) and false otherwise.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#isTransitionGroup())

Comment: Note: You can do this in code by calling `ViewGroup.setTransitionGroup` for API >= 21 or on all API by `ViewGroupCompat.setTransitionGroup`

Comment: Not sure if its me or the online documentation but this was key to my success! No matter what I did adding a target to any transition would make it not work - until I added android:transitionGroup=false.

I see how that the culprit was the fact that I had a background on my parent view group...

Documentation states:
The default for a ViewGroup is false unless it has a background.